# Navigation Architecture Component - Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-components

I am using Navigation Component with Navigation Drawer.

1. I have added Fragments for each Navigation item in the menu.
2. Add NavHostFragment where this Fragment will be swapped
3. Then added Fragments as Destinations
4. I want master Detail Navigation i.e. 
   start destination -> fragment 2 
   back button -> start destination 
   start destination -> fragment 2 -> fragment 3 -> fragment 4 
   back button -> start destination
5. My question is whether I should add any connections to this graph?
6. I also need to have one menu item which is just logout function call not fragment swapping, so I could not configure it with default setup

   ```
   val navController = findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment)
   nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController)
   ```

But rather have to use

```
nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.navSignOut -> {
                loginViewModel.logout()
            }
            else -> {
                val navController = findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment)
                navController.navigate(item.itemId)
            }
        }

        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
        return true
    }
```

I also need to show Login Activity above (modally) the Main App Activity with Navigation Drawer. Can I use Navigation  Graph for it and how? 
Login Activity should: on back button -> close app, if logged out -> start above main activity, if logged in go to main activity

So I have to questions: 
1. Should I use any actions?
2. Should I use custom navigation for drawer or setupWithNavController()?
3. What about modal login activity navigation?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Looking for the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Michael, navigation architecture it is not that easy to understand at the beginning, what you want to is not the exception. But as this navigation is new, I just suggest you to follow the code lab.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#0

I see for instance your line to close the drawer. The code lab has instructions on how to setup the nav drawer with navigation and the UI

I hope it helps you.

Comment: How I can combine Navigation Drawer and tabs using the Navigation Controller?

Comment: You can not, and you shouldn't. The Tabs are not meant to modify navigation, it is stated in the guidelines "Tabs organize content across different screens, data sets, and other interactions" the usage "Tabs organize and allow navigation between groups of content that are related and at the same level of hierarchy." (https://material.io/components/tabs/#) That is why you won't find how to do it anywhere. Although there is a Bottom Navigation component that can be use with Navigation Arch

Comment: And would it be ok if I combine bottom navigation with Drawer?

Comment: yes, but it is better to use one or the other. I recommend you to read the guidelines to know what is better for your app.

Answer (score 0):

The part I undrestood from your question is how to navigate to logout.

Usually when the user clicks on logout you want to log them out and navigate to a startup screen.

So you need to add your startup activity to nav_graph.